# How to delete object(s) from project when using deploy method?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

When you delete an obsolete object from a project/solution, what's the best way to transfer this change into production? Does deploying have an option for this?

EDIT: This is a database project in Visual Studio 2008, deploying to SQL Server 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any automated way of deleting obsolete objects. We use a database diff and then write delete statements manually here.

If someone has a better solution I would love to hear it (we're on VS 2005, not 2008, but I imagine that wouldn't make too much difference)

Comment: That seems like a lot of work, manually deleting it from the project, the server, and the source control system. Compared to adding stuff which is really easy and automated.